# What are these red lasers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

These just appeared. What's going on?!

[image]

[image]

They seem to follow me around, but appear patchily. What have I done?

Comment: You're currently FIRIN' YUOR LAZORS. There is no option to turn them off because they are awesome.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They are marking locations where hostile mobs can spawn.

It is a feature of [Not Enough Items](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/909223-125145-smp-chickenbones-mods/) (NEI) and the default key (configurable) to toggle this on and off is <kbd>F7</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

Those show tiles where it is dark enough for monsters to spawn, I believe. Check in the controls to see if there is a key bound to something like that. You may have hit it by accident.

Comment: Which mod adds this?

Comment: I'm not sure, I haven't seen it myself. I used to have a local modpack that let me do this, so I just recognize the effect.